# Returning Resource in Try-With-Resource block

Tags: postgresql, try-with-resources

I'm in a situation where I have a function executing an SQL query whose results I would like to pass into a function that will save them as a CSV file. I wrote this try-with-resource block to take advantage of AutoClosable:

```
public static ResultSet getRiderHistory(File file, Calendar date) throws FileNotFoundException {

    try(Connection conn = new dbConnect("psql", "localhost", ****, "*****", "****", "").get_conn();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = createPreparedStatement(conn, getSerialFromFile(file), date);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {

        if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
            throw new SQLException("ResultSet retuned empty!");
        }

        return rs;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but the compiler is quitting with this error:

```
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /home/****
    [javac] /home/****/****.java:50: error: missing return statement
    [javac]     }
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] 1 error
```

I think I understand the reason the nature of the problem. I'm guessing it's because I'm trying to return a resource that's going to be closed, instead of a copy of the results like I want (please correct me if I'm wrong). As I'm new to Java, however, I don't really know how to resolve this and get the results I want. Should I use a `finally` on the ResultSet somehow, or ought I change the return value into something like an `ArrayList`, an object that doesn't have to closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the error is saying that your last `catch (Exception)` block does not return a value.  The body of the *try* returns a value, and the first *catch* throws an exception, but the last *catch* does nothing except print a stacktrace.  All return paths in this method must either 1) return a `ResultSet` or `null`, or 2) throw an exception.